# Notepad in WPF, copy/paste function

Tags: c#, wpf, copy-paste, notepad

Trying to create a notepad, with its default functions...Trouble with copying and pasting text. Here's code, copy function is work (try ctrl+v) but pasting no

```
private void MenuCopy_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (NotepadText.SelectedText.Length > 0) Clipboard.SetText(NotepadText.SelectedText, TextDataFormat.Text);
        else MessageBox.Show("Nothing is selected", "Notepad", MessageBoxButton.OK);
}

private void MenuPaste_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    NotepadText.Text.Insert(NotepadText.CaretIndex, Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with 'pasting no'? Pasting doesn't work? What does happen when you click the paste button? Does it throw an exception? Does it just do nothing? In that case, did you try putting a breakpoint in `MenuPaste_OnClick` to verify that it is being called?

Comment: Pasting doesn't work, its called, but do nothing

Comment: Try assigning `Clipboard.GetText(TextDataFormat.Text)` to a local variable inside `MenuPaste_OnClick` so you can inspect its value while debugging.

Comment: It could just be that the UI doesn't get updated.  Hard to say without seeing more (e.g. XAML).  For what you're trying to do, your own answer below is probably the best way to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, went another way

```
<MenuItem Header="Edit">
            <MenuItem Header="Copy" Name="MenuCopy"
                      Command="Copy"></MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Header="Paste" Name="MenuPaste"
                      Command="Paste"></MenuItem>
</MenuItem>
```

but if you have any suggestions about previous, please let me know